# weak P-point that is not a P-point

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, filters

Is there a fairly simple example of a compact Hausdorff space with a weak P-point (i.e. a point that is not in the closure of any countable set to which it does not belong) that is a not a P-point (a P-point being one which is not in the closure of the union of any countable family of closed subsets which do not contain it)?

Kunen showed that $\beta {\bf N}\setminus {\bf N}$ has many weak P-points which are not P-points but these are not very visible. I would like something simpler, like the non-isolated P-point in $\omega_1+1$.

Here is a fairly simple example, but which fails to be locally compact at the critical point. Let $X=(\omega+1)\times (\omega_1+1)$, and for $i=1,2,\dots , \omega$, let $W_i$ be the copy of $\omega_1+1$
corresponding to $i$. Let $x_i$ be the non-isolated P-point $\omega_1$ in $W_i$.

Let $Y=X\setminus \{ x_i: 1\le i<\omega\}$. Then $x_{\omega}$ is a weak P-point in $Y$ but it is not a P-point
because it lies in the closure of the countable union of closed sets $\bigcup_{1\le i<\omega} W_i\setminus\{x_i\}$.

Comment: P-points and weak P-points are studied exclusively in connection with the homogeneity question of $\omega^\ast$. E.g. [van Mill](http://topology.nipissingu.ca/tp/reprints/v04/tp04221s.pdf) shows that spaces of this type ($F$-spaces) have $2^{2^\omega}$ weak P-points that are not P-points. I think the proof looks quite accessible. Points are "just" special ultrafilters..

Comment: Working in C$^*$-algebras, I have several times run into P-points as an exceptional case requiring special attention. I don't think I have ever encountered weak P-points except in interim proofs which eventually got improved to cope with P-points as well.

Comment: Yes, that's where P-points were first defined (in "rings of continuous functions"-theory), but that is very closely related to $\beta X$ theory (due to the ideals in $C(X)$ and compactfications connection). Weak P-points are a compromise because they're sort of similar to P-points but "always" exist, etc. They've not been studied much (or at all) in general spaces (that are not extremally diconnected, F-spaces or similar). So my impression is that "natural" examples outside of this realm will be hard to come by.